# Stack true results in output buffer

Tags: opencl

I'm new in OpenCL, but worked for many years with opengl\webgl for drawing and GPGPUs.

I want to check intersection of polyline with others. Polyline is a set of connected segments - Like LINE_STRIP.

I'm have polylines. each polyline has many points. I put all in one buffer. when the buffer look like [pntsCount, x, y, x, y....,pntsCount,x,y,....].
let's call it - points buffer.

In addition I have a buffer that holds the indices of the beginning of each polyline, for example the indices of the 'pntsCount' values.
lets call it - starts buffer

My global is the amount of the polylines = the length of the starts buffer.

In each work item i'm running over my current polyline (from the polylines buffer) and check intersection with the single polyline.

Today, i provide my kernel output buffer of the size of the starts buffer for holding whether there is intersection or not.

In this way, after the kernel ended. i'm running over the buffer in the host, and checking which has true\false value.

My question is,
Can i just stack my true results in the output buffer, instead of true/false values for all polylines.
What i mean is, Saving in my output only the indices of the polylines that does intersect my single polyline.

so my result buffer will be for exmaple [4,24,10,...]
and not [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1....]

For this i need to have a variable thats holds the current index in the results buffer to set the value and then increment it for next result.
And before the first kernel invoked i need to set it to 0.

I saw that there is an atomic_inc, in addition i can achieve that with local memory and barriers..

Can someone make an order into it for me ? and maybe an example how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the bottleneck?  The output of data or the calculation?
If it is the calculation, then go for a atomic approach.

You can do it this way:

- Use `atomic_inc()` on a global variable, get the returned value. And write to that address the line_id or the line data itself.
- For an extra optimization, collect locally all the lines that are true, then do an `atomic_add()` globally, and after that write to the returned values all the line_id or data.

*NOTE: The atomic functions return the value that was there before the operation.
So, if you atomic_add(10), you will get a 0, and the next atomic_add() will get a 10. So it is very useful to use that value as the base address to write to a memory region.*

If you decide to write the data. You will end up with a packed structure that you can copy out. If you write the id, you will have to post process it later on. Depends on the size of your data you can choose for one or another approach.

Example:

---

Host:

```
//Create a buffer to hold a counter
cl::Buffer counter(&context, CL_READ_WRITE, sizeof(cl_uint));

while(running){
    //Reset it
    cl_uint zero_counter = 0;
    queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(counter, CL_FALSE, 0, sizeof(cl_uint), &zero_counter);
    //Launch the kernel
    ...
    //Read it back
    cl_uint data_counter = 0;
    queue.enqueueReadBuffer(counter, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_uint), &data_counter);
    //Read back other buffers using data_counter's returned value
    ...
}
```

Device:

```
__kernel mykern(__global uint * counter, ...){
    ...
    if(condition){ //Condition to add it to the output buffer
        uint addr = atomic_inc(counter);
        out[addr] = ... //Write it there
    }
}
```

Comment: The bottelneck is the host that need to read and run over this long results buffer, in order to find what was intersected. can be that nothing was intersected and i will still run over all the buffer to figure it out. Is it possible also to get this global variable in the end? so i will know how many intersection was there?

Comment: Added a clarifying example

Comment: It is was i did in end :) Although, The counter parameter in the kernel should be pointer (add `*`), and remove the `&` in the `atomic_inc` otherwise it didn't pass build

Comment: Yes you are right, I forgot that CL parameters are pointers. (The problem of coding without a compiler at hand)